# Export SQL structure and data from PHPMyAdmin inside web application

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a client that use my web application for debts control. He wants to save and backup all data so if something happened to his laptop, he could repair his data.

I told him to enter to phpmyadmin and click on export, but he think that it is little bit complicated for him and for his employees.

So I need to add a new button to the app so he can click on it and export an sql file that contain all data and all database tables and structure using PHP PDO of a specific database (not all phpmyadmin dbs).

Is it possible ? I searched and couldn't find something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button and on the back-end execute this MYSQL command line command using `exec` of php on button click.

```
mysqldump -u'username' -p'password' database_name > /path/backup.sql
```

You can download the file directly in browser using the code given below

```
      $fileName =  "/path/backup.sql";
       if (file_exists($fileName)) {
           header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
           header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
           header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($fileName).'"');
           header('Expires: 0');
           header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
           header('Pragma: public');
           header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
           readfile($fileName);
           exit;
       }
```

Comment: Can I let the client save the file in a directory that he want it ?

Comment: yes... /path/backup.sql can be d:/mysql_backups/backup.sql @LaraCh

Comment: I am getting an empty file.sql in the directory and the downloadable file is empty too, I am using this line: `mysqldump -u'root' -p'root' my_db_name > backup.sql`

Comment: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
dump -u'root' -p'root' dentist > backup.sql' at line 1`

Comment: there is no space between mysql and dump  @LaraCh

Comment: i know, it is typing error from me, at the cmd, their is no space

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113289/discussion-between-danyal-sandeelo-and-lara-ch).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

backup_tables('localhost','root','password','your_database');

/* backup the db OR just a table */
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{

    $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($name,$link);

    //get all of the tables
    if($tables == '*')
    {
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
    }

    //cycle through
    foreach($tables as $table)
    {
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

        $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
        $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                for($j=0; $j < $num_fields; $j++)
                {
                    $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                    $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                    if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                    if ($j < ($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                }
                $return.= ");\n";
            }
        }
        $return.="\n\n\n";
    }

    //save file
    $handle = fopen('db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');
    fwrite($handle,$return);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

You can download the sql file by running the following code:

```
<?php

$files = glob(dirname(__FILE__) . "/*.sql");


foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
    }
}
```

> This code use `mysql` api, I think you can easily convert it into `mysqli`.
>   This code will backup all the tables of your database.

Comment: Not at all. I started working with PHP and PDO. I don't even know mysqli

Comment: You don't need anything else to run this code. I mention about `mysqli` only for the reason that using `mysql` api isn't a good practice. Just run the code in your browser with your database credentials and see if it fulfill your needs....

Comment: Hundreds of errors about mysql that it was deprecated, egex function deprecated, mysqli needs 2 parameters and so on

Comment: Use `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` in the top of the code... Btw you should still get the sql backup in the directory you have run the script.

Comment: okay and how to download the file into a new directory ? The client don't know that he would go to wamp/www/...

Comment: I have updated the answer by providing the code for downloading sql from web directory to local machine. Please check.

Comment: I think the best solution will be using `cron job` to schedule regular database backup.